# Orbeon forms - dynamic visibility of sections causes incorrect rendering of date field on mobile (iOS)

Tags: dynamic, datepicker, orbeon, hidden-field

We have an Orbeon form with 2 sections. First (section A) is displayed by the default, and only when all fields are filled-in, new section opens up (section B) with different set of fields. Everything works normally on desktop, but the problem happens when accessing from mobile device (**iOS only**, Android works).

*Screenshot* - 1st section opened by default, notice the date field rendering (with mm/dd/yyyy) and user is able to select the date normally.
[image: Section A - Date field working]

But, when Section B gets displayed as a result of filling everything in Section A, date field from section B is not rendered in the same way, thus disabling the possibility to select a date (**datepicker is not opened, instead of it a normal keyboard is opened**).

[image: Section B - Date field not rendering]

Based on my research, due to **dynamic visibility of sections**, not everything is loaded for Section B and Orbeon engine is not changing type of the hidden input field to "date". Instead it's configured as a "text" type, that's why the keyboard appears on IOS devices. On Android devices, the form acts as on desktop, hence the calendar pops up.

Does anyone have an idea if this could be something which can be done to fix this as part of Orbeon forms?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble; I've been able to reproduce the problem, and for now created [this issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3155). We've scheduled this for our next release, and will post a follow-up here when this is fixed.

Comment: Hi @avernet, thanks for the update, we will implement a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: Here we go @lazard, the issue is fixed, and the fix will be in Orbeon Forms 2017.1. Thank you for letting us know about it! And let me know if you are using Orbeon Forms PE and need a fix before that.

Comment: Thanks @avernet, currently working in a development environment, so there is no need for a earlier fix.

Comment: Got it, and if course just let me know if that changes, and you need a fix earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3155), and it is fixed in Orbeon Forms 2017.1.